# move div tag to the right through CSS

Tags: html, css, tags, css-float

I have 3 div tag that I aligned on the left and are floating left.
The problem is above there is another content of `width: 80rem;` and I would like to kind of centre them.
I tried so many combinations, but I am unable to let start the 1st picture aligned to the object above.

CSS

```
.beachcontent{
background-color: #FAFCE8;
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border: 0.1rem solid black;
padding: 0.2rem;
width: 26.6rem;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 2.5px;
margin-right: 2.5px;
float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="beachcontent">  <!--starting div beachcontent-->
<h4>Sardinia</h4>
<a href="sardinia.html"><img src="images/sardinia.jpg" width="330" height="220" alt="Sardinia"></a>
</div>                      <!--ending div beachcontent-->
<div class="beachcontent">  <!--starting div beachcontent-->
<h4>Sicily</h4>
<a href="sicily.html"><img src="images/sicily.jpg" width="330" height="220" alt="Sicily"></a>
</div>                      <!--ending div beachcontent-->
<div class="beachcontent">  <!--starting div beachcontent-->
<h4>Elba</h4>
<a href="elba.html"><img src="images/elba.jpg" width="330" height="220" alt="Elba"></a>
</div>                      <!--ending div beachcontent-->
</main>
<!--several br lines to display hr below beachcontent divs-->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<!--TO BE FIXED IF POSSIBLE-->
```

another small issue is that I have to use several `<br>` lines to display `<hr>` below beachcontent divs, which is not really elegant. Is there a better way to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `margin: auto` but then you have the left, right and bottom margins set?

Comment: Because margin:auto should center it. Left right and bottom margins are for leave a bit of space around. Sorry for those mistakes but I am a beginner.

Comment: That's not how it works. `margin: auto` sets the margins for left right top and bottom to auto. So first you're setting all of them to auto, then you're overwriting left, right and bottom after. The only margin still set to auto is top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found a solution for your problem.
I grouped all your div's inside another div and put it a width of 82rem and a auto margin. You have to customize the width to fit your design.
Try the code below:

```css
.beachcontent{
background-color: #FAFCE8;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border: 0.1rem solid black;
padding: 0.2rem;
width: 26.6rem;
text-align: center;
display:inline-block;
}
#middle{
  width: 82rem;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="middle">
<div class="beachcontent">  <!--starting div beachcontent-->
<h4>Sardinia</h4>
<a href="sardinia.html"><img src="images/sardinia.jpg" width="330" height="220" alt="Sardinia"></a>
</div>                      <!--ending div beachcontent-->
<div class="beachcontent">  <!--starting div beachcontent-->
<h4>Sicily</h4>
<a href="sicily.html"><img src="images/sicily.jpg" width="330" height="220" alt="Sicily"></a>
</div>                      <!--ending div beachcontent-->
<div class="beachcontent">  <!--starting div beachcontent-->
<h4>Elba</h4>
<a href="elba.html"><img src="images/elba.jpg" width="330" height="220" alt="Elba"></a>
</div><!--ending div beachcontent-->
</div>
</main>
<!--several br lines to display hr below beachcontent divs-->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<!--TO BE FIXED IF POSSIBLE-->
```

Can you please clarify the problem with your break line tag?
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks it works!!! Can you maybe help me to understand why exactly 82rem? Thanks again!!

Comment: 82 rem is a little more than the total of the 3 inline divs and that will keep them inline and give them auto margin